# CSS Auto Sync not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and for a particular project that I'm working on the CSS auto-sync doesn't seem to be working. It's definitely enabled and seems to work okay on other projects.
Does anyone have any ideas what would stop it from working, a search on Google hasn't yielded any results.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't sync until you save. Also, I usually do all my style edits from the browser itself because of the erratic behavior I've encountered as well and switching between windows.

Comment: It's definitely been saved. Seems weird that it would do it for one project but not another

Comment: Does refresh update it?

Comment: Yes, refreshing does update it

Comment: Are you using the Internal Browser within Visual Studio or using another major browser? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/13/css-auto-sync-and-javascript-selection-mapping-in-page-inspector/

Comment: I'm using Chrome. As I said, it's fine with other projects, just this one.

Comment: From the Browser Link Dashboard, "Debugging must be enabled in Web.Config and Development server must be running on .NET 4.0 or later." And your `Enable CSS Auto-Sync` is checked? If you have static HTML pages, from what I've read, more setup may be required.

Comment: Debugging is enabled, I'm running .net 4.5 and I have enabled CSS Auto-Sync. They're not static html pages, they're .net web forms. Still no joy getting it to work though

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the CSS Autosync feature. It’s a bug of Visual Studio, if you use Google Chrome you need to disable this feature because you get an error. I had the same problem.

Regards
Yannik